# Binding interface/domain to CouchDB

Tags: http, interface, couchdb

I'm running CouchDB on a windows 2008 Server and it works good on localhost (127.0.0.1) but when I try to change it to a specific IP or all interface (0.0.0.0) then it doesnt work.

I would like to run CouchDB on a specific domain on the standard port. Even when changed to 0.0.0.0 it wouldn't list to ether domain.tld or another IP. What am I doing wrong?

**local.ini**

```
[httpd]
port = 5984
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

**logfile**

```
[Tue, 09 Oct 2012 11:05:44 GMT] [info] [<0.35.0>] Apache CouchDB has started on http://127.0.0.1:5984/
[Tue, 09 Oct 2012 11:09:40 GMT] [info] [<0.2205.0>] 127.0.0.1 - - 'GET' / 200
[Tue, 09 Oct 2012 11:15:44 GMT] [info] [<0.35.0>] Apache CouchDB has started on http://0.0.0.0:5984/
```

Comment: Solved it! CouchDB process was still running on the server. **Killed the process** and **started CouchDB again** and it worked.

Comment: Tried that but users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. I'll do that when the time has passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! CouchDB process was still running on the server. **Killed the process** and **started CouchDB again** and it worked.